# ¿Como filtrar las opciones de un campo select en base a otro campo del mismo tipo en un formulario Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

El problema que tengo es el siguiente, quiero acceder al valor seleccionado en tiempo real de un campo select en mi formulario y en base a este, filtrar las opciones para el cliente.

El campo en específico es el que corresponde en el model Request al atributo product_type, el cual según la opción que seleccione a partir de un choice, se filtre el segundo campo, el de product (Product tiene una fk que apunta al product_type)

mis models.py

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nombre", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Producto", max_length=250)
    price = models.IntegerField("Price")
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Request(models.Model):
    CUSTOMER_TYPE = [
        ('IND', 'Individuos'),
        ('NEG', 'NEGOCIOS'),
    ]

    COMPANIES = [
        ('CLA', 'Claro'),
        ('PER', 'Personal'),
        ('TUE', 'Tuenti'),
        ('MOV', 'Movistar'),
        ('OTR', 'Otro'),
    ]

    types = ProductType.objects.all()
    PRODUCT_TYPE = []

    for o in types:
        key = o.name[:3]
        value = o.name
        t = (key,value)
        PRODUCT_TYPE.append(t)
    

    customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CUSTOMER_TYPE)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length = 150, choices = PRODUCT_TYPE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_sale = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    request_source = models.ForeignKey(RequestSource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    #Portability
    current_company = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CUSTOMER_TYPE)
    mobile_to_carry = models.CharField("Número a portar", max_length=13)
    pin = models.IntegerField("Pin")

    #Internet services
    address_coordinates = models.TextField("Coordenadas del Domicilio", max_length=400)
    other_references = models.TextField("Otras Referencias", max_length=400)
    
    #Aditional information
    attached_files = models.FileField(upload_to='media/adjuntos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    comments = models.TextField("Comentarios", max_length=300)
    
    #Request status
    request_status = models.ForeignKey(RequestStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} - {self.product} - {self.customer}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_of_sale']
```

mis forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:

        model = Request
        fields = ['customer_type','product_type','product','request_source',]

        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(type = self.product_type)
        
        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.product = Product.objects.filter(type = self.product_type) 
            form.instance.seller = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

mis views.py

```
class RequestCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Request
    template_name = 'request/request.html'
    form_class = RequestForm
    second_form_class = CustomerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RequestCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET)
        
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            request = form.save(commit = False)
            request.customer = form2.save()
            request.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form = form, form2=form2))
```

Lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo, si tengo Manteca, Queso y Leche serían de tipo Lácteos y Vino y Cerveza, de tipo Bebidas.

Si yo en el formulario elijo tipo de producto (product_type) = Lácteos, que en el siguiente campo productos (product) solo aparezcan filtrados los que son de tipo Lacteos y viceversa si elijo otro type_product. No se donde debo hacer el filtro, si en el form o en la view o si incluso se puede hacer en el model o en el html.

En el HTML el campo product_type se muestra como un Select con los tipos de productos que tengo creados en la base de datos y los product se muestran de igual forma pero no estan filtrados. QUIERO ACLARAR que me gustaría que el filtro se realice en tiempo real.

> Intenté algunas soluciones desde el forms.py de la REQUEST, como la que traté de intentar en el **init** y en el form_valid de filtrar los productos con el orm de django y con una queryset pero sin éxito alguno

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude lograr utilizando la librería **django-smart-select**

https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects

Muy sencilla de usar, seguir bien los pasos de la documentación. En los modelos realizar correctamente la importación **from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey** y cambiar la foreign key respectiva por chainedforeignkey y no olvidar habilitar USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True en settings.py

Tampoco olvidar de incluir en los templates {{ form.media.js }} dentro del form correspondiente, son dos scripts de javascript necesarios para que funcione el select anidado